# How can I obtain thread dumps for Dataflow Python processes?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When a Dataflow worker becomes stuck it would be helpful to be able to get the thread dumps of Python process that the worker is having trouble with.

How would I identify and obtain the threadz dump of a stuck Python process?

Comment: Also, if it helps, this feature should come in beam 2.6.0, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

1. [SSH into the worker machine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq#is-it-possible-to-access-my-jobs-worker-machines-compute-engine-vms-while-my-pipeline-is--running).
2. Run `docker ps`. Example output may look like:

   ```
   CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                ... NAMES
   ...
   0649a3f76a4a   dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/python:2.4.0 ... k8s_python.b30867f0_dataflow-wordcount-ma-07022224-6ad4-harness-r7cy_default_a9d4faf05c7e404114002f06ca702ecc_6e2cabdf
   ...
   ```

   Note the CONTAINER ID for the container named `...python...`.
3. Log into the container with `docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID bash`.
4. Find the `threadz` port for the worker process in the worker logs with:

   `cat /var/log/dataflow/python-dataflow-*-json.log | grep 'Status HTTP server'`.

   Example output may look like:

   ```
   {"severity": "INFO",..., "message": "Status HTTP server running at localhost:37735", "logger": "root:batchworker.py:status_server"}
   ```

   Note that there may be multiple worker processes running, each having their own `threadz` port.
5. Sample `threadz` content with `curl localhost:$PORT`.